# Writing output in multiple files in Hadoop

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [MultipleOutputFormat in hadoop](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3491105/multipleoutputformat-in-hadoop)

I want to write the files according to months using map-reduce in hadoop. If data is from January month then the data should be wriiten in jan-file and likewise for each month there should be seperate file.

How Can I create such file in hadoop mapredude. I am trying for recursive map-reduce but not getting how to implement it?

Pls suggest me some solution.

Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use the [MultipleOutputFormat](http://hadoop.apache.org/mapreduce/docs/r0.21.0/api/org/apache/hadoop/mapred/lib/MultipleOutputFormat.html) class, the output file name can be deduced from the key and the reducer output value from the reducer. [MultipleOutputFormat#generateFileNameForKeyValue](http://hadoop.apache.org/mapreduce/docs/r0.21.0/api/org/apache/hadoop/mapred/lib/MultipleOutputFormat.html#generateFileNameForKeyValue%28K,%20V,%20java.lang.String%29) has to be implemented in the user defined OutputFormat class.

```
static class MyMultipleOutputFormat extends MultipleOutputFormat<Text, Text> {
    protected String generateFileNameForKeyValue(Text key, Text value, String name) {
        String keyString = key.toString();
        String valueString = value.toString();
        #return a combination of keyString and valueString 
    }
}
```

Comment: Does not work with latest version of Hadoop (new mapreduce library instead of the old mapred). That's why I downvoted.