# Map job which splits file into small ones and generates names of these files on reduce stage

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce

Given big file A, I need to iterate over records of that file and for each record

- extract value of certain field (status)
- add this record to the file with name "status_" + value
- emit that status value to reducer

so output would contain set of files with records, grouped by statuses, and some file with list of statuses

ideally, it should

- place files with statuses under 'output_dir/statuses/status_nnn' (where nnn is actual status value),
- 'output_dir/status_list' would contain statuses one per line

Is that possible to do with hadoop? I found out how to generate filename per record with this [example](https://sites.google.com/site/hadoopandhive/home/how-to-write-output-to-multiple-named-files-in-hadoop-using-multipletextoutputformat), but not sure how to do separation of records and enumerate statuses.

I don't know in advance which statuses could be in those records.

Answer (score 0):

In the map phase you can do 2 emits per record:  and `<list_statuses, status>`. The 'list_statusses' must be a unique key you choose in advance. Then in the reduce phase your behaviour depends on the key, if it equals your special key then you emit a file with the statuses (this reduce function will store all statuses in a Set for example) otherwise generate the `<status,field>` file.

Does this make sense to you?

Comment: Not really, as far as I understood - I have to create files inside my reduce job, so either I set number of reducers to 1, or I need to create files per reducer, which will need some aggregation later on. I don't really like both ways.

Comment: I don't know the details but you can definitely specify that every key of the reducer has to end up in a seperate file: I think this post explains how you can tackle this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3491105/multipleoutputformat-in-hadoop

Comment: In that example I need to know possible values of status in advance, which I don't know.

Comment: No, you don't. You use the reducer key to create the filename, and the reducer key = the status?

Comment: I think there's some sort of misunderstanding. I need map task to produce different files, depending on status column in record from thet input file, and then I want to aggregate those distinct status values in separate file. So I can find the files with records later on by simply iterate over content of file with statuses and building the names like 'status_255'.

Comment: Maybe add an example because I am still convinced I answered your question. The outputfiles will be generated, one per reduce task, and there is one reduce task which will emit the status file, the map task only create the key value pairs.