# Separate output per file in Hadoop and Amazon EMR/S3

Tags: hadoop, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, hadoop-streaming, amazon-emr

I'm working on a project that analyzes the words in books using Hadoop.  I have a program similar to the standard word count example ([see here](http://wiki.apache.org/hadoop/WordCount)).  The program currently counts all of the words in all of the files in a directory and combines it all together.  However, I also need to get a word count and individual output for each file processed, or at least something that will give me per-file word counts.  How can I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> It Seems you are looking for `MultipleOutputFormat`
>
> There is alerady impplementation code here [link1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3491105/multipleoutputformat-in-hadoop) and complete
>   explanation and example code here [link2](http://grepalex.com/2013/05/20/multipleoutputs-part1/#MultipleOutputFormat). Just map your outputfile as
>   input filename or whatever you wish, The files will get
>   "/outputfolder/part-nnnnn" for each group, name "part" can be changed,
>   where nnnnn is partition ID associated with the reduce task. This
>   can't be dodged, you have to rename / merge these files on the HDFS.